# PHP get text between multiple custom tags

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I need to parse a custom template file.

Lets say my template file looks like this.

```
@section('section1')
    some content
@endsection

@section('section2')
    some more content
@endsection
```

As a result of the parsing i need the following result:

```
array(
    'section1' => 'some content',
    'section2' => 'some more content'
);
```

I tried to get the section names first with this code:

```
$sectionPattern = '/(?<=\@section\().*?(?=\))/';
preg_match_all($sectionPattern, $this->fileContents, $sections);
```

which works as expected. The result looks like:

```
$sections = array(
    array(
        0 => 'section1',
        1 => 'section2'
    )
);
```

If i try to get the content for each section with this code:

```
foreach($sections[0] as $section) {
    $contentPattern = '/(?<=\@section\(' . $section . '\)).*?(?=@endsection)/';
    preg_match_all($contentPattern, $this->fileContents, $content);
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($content);
}
```

i only get empty arrays and i cant figure out why.

Also, if you anyone sees a more elegant way to get the desired result. I'm open for suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get both matches in one pattern and then combine them.  You don't show the content being multi-line but this will handle it.  The `array_map('trim', $sections[2])` gets rid on the whitespace/newlines at either end of the content:

```
preg_match_all("/@section\('([^']+)'\)([^@]+)/", $this->fileContents, $sections);
$sections = array_combine($sections[1], array_map('trim', $sections[2]));
```

Comment: Incredible! I still have much to lern with regular expressions. Thanks!